# How do I pause a splash screen in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

How do I pause a splash screen in Codename One?

It seems that example (native demo) uses replaceAndWait(...) method, but in my situation I have nothing to replace but I just want the screen to wait for a few seconds.

I tried to use Thread.wait(n) but it crashed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `UITimer` inside the `processBackground()` in the `StateMachine.java` file to delay your splash screen.

If you are not using `StateMachine` (Splash not created in GUI Builder), delay next form from showing the same way by using `UITimer` in your splash manipulation method that could be residing in your main class.

```
@Override
protected boolean processBackground(final Form f) {
    //depends on your splash form's name
    if ("Splash".equalsIgnoreCase(f.getName())) {
        new UITimer(() -> {
            //show your next form here
        }).schedule(4000, false, f);// set the time to a longer time, currently 4 seconds
    }
    return false;
}
```